# SQL Select items with only certain attributes

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. Config, capability, and config_capability which associates the first two.

A config can have more than one capability so config_capability could look like

```
id | config_id | capability_id
1    1           1
2    1           2
3    2           1
4    2           2
5    2           3
```

I want to find the configs that have **only** certain capabilities.

```
SELECT
    config.name
FROM
    config
JOIN
    config_capability AS cc
ON
    config.id = cc.config_id
JOIN
    capability
ON
    cc.capability_id = capability.id
WHERE
    config.node_count <= 4
AND cc.capability_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM capability
    WHERE capability.name = 'cap1'
    OR capability.name = 'cap2')
GROUP BY config.name
HAVING COUNT(cc.config_id) = 2
```

This query gives me config 1 and config 2 but I only want to find configs with capabilities 1 and 2 not 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as below no need to use extra subquery while you have that table in join

```
SELECT
    c.name
FROM
    config c
JOIN
    config_capability AS cc
ON
    c.id = cc.config_id
JOIN
    capability ca
ON
    cc.capability_id = ca.id
 WHERE
    config.node_count <= 4
GROUP BY c.name
 HAVING sum(ca.name NOT IN('cap1','cap2')) = 0
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80ce3/12)

Comment: Thanks, this helps me find configs with only the capabilities I'm looking for but it also selects configs with a subset of the capabilities needed.

Comment: @user3753975 i didn't get your point can you update your question accordingly with all brief

Comment: I got it. Adding 'AND sum(ca.name IN('cap1','cap2')) = 2' finds the configs with all the capabilities and none extra. Thanks!

Comment: @user3753975 if it helps then mark this answer as accepted by clicking check mark under answer score

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
HAVING COUNT(cc.config_id) = 2 and max(cc.config_id)<3
```